# Reading an array from stdin using input() function throws an EOF error

Tags: python

Basically, I wish to sum the elements of the array provided in stdin. Why is it saying that list index is out of range? Is there anything special about the python `input()` function?

```py
length = int(input())
li = []

for i in range(0, length):
    li[i] = int(input())
    
sum = 0
for item in li:
    sum = sum + item
```

Input

- first line : length of array
- second line : elements of the array.

EDIT : second line is a single string, not space separated integers.

```
3
1 2 3
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 6, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: There's nothing special about `input`; you can't just assign to a non-existent element of a list. Make that `li.append(int(input()))` and it should work.

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last): File Main.py , line 7, in li.append(int(input())) EOFError: EOF when reading a line.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second line of input turned out to be a single string and not space separated integers.

So I had to split the string, then convert the strings to integers to calculate their sum. Some of the methods mentioned above didn't work.

The list comprehension method will work in the space separated case, and is perfectly fine.

```py
length = int(input())
l = input().split() # List of strings of integers.

S = 0
for item in l:
    S += int(item) # Converting string to int

print(S)
```

Answer (score 2):

your question pretty much got answered, I just wanna show you a couple of tricks to make your program more simple and pythonic.

Instead of the for-loop try:
`li = [int(i) for i in input().split(" ")]`

And instead of the way you're calculating sum, try:
`sum(li)`

or even better:
`sumOfItems = sum(int(i) for i in input().split(" "))`

Comment: If following this path, you can get one step further by removing the [] from the last example. This will avoid generating an intermediate list, sum will use the generator directly.

Comment: I  had no idea that you could do that, thanks for the info!! I've edited the answer with the change that you suggested.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know you could write an expression in the sum() method.

Answer (score 1):

The thing with python lists is that you **cannot assign a particular value** to a position when that **position originally does not exist**, that is, the length of the list is less than the position that you want to change.

What you are trying to do is assign the value to a particular position in the list (called index) but since the list is empty, it's length is 0 and hence the index is out of range( that is it is not available for modifiying. That is why python is raising *Index out of range* error.

What you can try is:

```
l=[]
length=int(input())
for i in length:
     l.append(int(input())
sum=0
for num in l:
     sum=sum+num
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in a single line without even taking in the length. But you have to enter space separated values in a single line:

```
s = 0
for item in list(map(int, input ().split())):
   s += item
```

If you want to input one integer per line, then you'll need the length(or a sentinel value):

```
s = 0
len = int(input())
li = [int(input ()) for _ in range(len)]
for item in li: 
    s  = s + item
```

Comment: Hey, this solution doesn't work. It shows a EOF error. Any workaround?

Answer (score -1):

You can't assign  values to locations of a list that doesn't exist

try this:

```
length = int(input())
li = list(range(length))

for i in range(0, length):
    li[i] = int(input())
    
sum = 0
for item in li:
    sum = sum + item
```

you can also do something like this:

```
length = int(input())
li = []

for i in range(0, length):
    li.append(int(input()))
    
total = sum(li)
print(total)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for you answer. The `li.append(int(input())` line shows a End Of File error. So I think it's not a good way to approach the problem. List comprehension is the easiest way IMO, but since I am a newbie, I would like to find a way to do it without list comprehensions.

Comment: I tested the code and it doesn't give any error message to me.An EOF erro can occur when the program fails to get an input, so the Error is probably in the way you are executing the code. More information on  how you are running it might help.

Comment: Actually, I am doing an online course and this was the practice question. The elements of array are a string in a single line. So your code works in the case where the integers are separate strings. I didn't know that was the case untill now.

Comment: If input is a string where the number a separated with spaces ( "1 2 3 4" for example) than you can do it in a single line of code: s = sum([int(x) for x in input("").split()])